# How do I sort rows with values across multiple columns?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of events with dates across multiple columns (just Jan and Feb shown here).

| Event | January | February |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Event A | 1/1/2023 |  |
| Event B |  | 2/28/2023 |
| Event C |  |  |
| Event D |  | 2/1/2023 |

How do I sort the events using dates across all the columns? This is the result I want:

| Event | January | February |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Event A | 1/1/2023 |  |
| Event D |  | 2/1/2023 |
| Event B |  | 2/28/2023 |
| Event C |  |  |

Comment: Is there just one date per event?

Comment: Sometimes there are two dates per event.

Comment: So in that case which one would you take for sorting on? Or would it create two rows for the same event?

Comment: Given your question, I would duplicate events with different dates. So in practice, there would be one date per event.

Comment: OK - can't look at it right now but will post something later on hopefully.

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
={A1:E1;sort(A2:E6,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,1)}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do this where I don't need to enter in each column manually into the sort function?

Comment: sorry can't think of one...

Answer (score 0):

You can use byrow and xlookup to find the (first) date in each row:

```
=ArrayFormula(let(rowcount,ROWS(TOCOL(Sheet2!A:A,1)),all,indirect("sheet2!a2:"&rowcount),dates,indirect("sheet2!b2:"&rowcount),datelist,byrow(dates,lambda(c,xlookup(true,(c<>""),c,""))),sort(all,datelist,1)))
```

[image]